# Have a categorie overview error in magento

Tags: magento

Here has been an error processing your request

> Bronmodel
>   "gomage_navigation/adminhtml_system_config_source_category_column"
>   niet gevonden voor attribuut "navigation_column_side"

Trace:

```
#0 /home3/tuinhuis/public_html/3works/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Bronmodel "goma...')
#1 /home3/tuinhuis/public_html/3works/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(201): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()
#2 /home3/tuinhuis/public_html/3works/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tab/Attributes.php(113): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset))
#3 /home3/tuinhuis/public_html/3works/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()
#4 /home3/tuinhuis/public_html/3works/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(862): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()
#5 /home3/tuinhuis/public_html/3works/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tabs.php(140): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 /home3/tuinhuis/public_html/3works/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(238): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs->_prepareLayout()
#7 /home3/tuinhuis/public_html/3works/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#8 /home3/tuinhuis/public_html/3works/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Edit/Form.php(55): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'tabs')
#9 /home3/tuinhuis/public_html/3works/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(238): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Edit_Form->_prepareLayout()
#10 /home3/tuinhuis/public_html/3works/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#11 /home3/tuinhuis/public_html/3works/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php(82): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...')
#12 /home3/tuinhuis/public_html/3works/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(238): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container->_prepareLayout()
#13 /home3/tuinhuis/public_html/3works/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#14 /home3/tuinhuis/public_html/3works/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
#15 /home3/tuinhuis/public_html/3works/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
#16 /home3/tuinhuis/public_html/3works/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#17 /home3/tuinhuis/public_html/3works/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#18 /home3/tuinhuis/public_html/3works/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#19 /home3/tuinhuis/public_html/3works/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#20 /home3/tuinhuis/public_html/3works/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#21 /home3/tuinhuis/public_html/3works/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php(201): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#22 /home3/tuinhuis/public_html/3works/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_CategoryController->editAction()
#23 /home3/tuinhuis/public_html/3works/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#24 /home3/tuinhuis/public_html/3works/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#25 /home3/tuinhuis/public_html/3works/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#26 /home3/tuinhuis/public_html/3works/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#27 /home3/tuinhuis/public_html/3works/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#28 {main}
```

I got this error when trying to enter my categorie overview of magento. This thing breaks, but don't know how to fix it...would be nice if somebody can help me out.

Comment: I've had issues with GoMage in my the past. Try disabling the GoMage module and see if that helps and if it does, you have a place to start looking / debugging.

Comment: There is no Gomage module at the backend anymore, so i can't disable it, do i have to reinstall it again? Or do you have some other advice? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Make sure GoMage is completely disabled by checking if the GoMage xml file is NOT in app/etc/modules

Comment: We have called in a company who fix this for us, i will find out how, and share this with you guys. Thanks for the responses..

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve this issue, follow below mentioned steps:

1. Remove all the files of the module from all directories (app,skin,js,etc)
2. Delete Columns from your Database Table = EAV_Attribute starting from navigation_ as these columsn are of gomage navigation extension.(eg: navigation_column_side)
3. Flush Cache

The error will be resolved.